# How to append data to a dataframe whithout overwriting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python but I need it for a personal project. And so I have this lump of code. The function is to create a table and update it as necessary. The problem is that the table keeps being overwritten and I don't know why. Also I'm struggling with correctly assigning the starting position of the new lines to append, and that's why `total` (ends up overwritten as well) and `pos` are there, but I haven't figured out how to correctly use them. Any tips?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

total ={}

entryTable = pd.read_csv("Entry_Table.csv")

newEntries = int(input("How many new entries?\n"))

for i in range(newEntries):
   ID = input ("ID?\n")
   VQ = int (input ("VQ?\n"))
   timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   entryTable.loc[i] = [timeStamp, ID, VQ]
   entryTable.to_csv("Inventory_Table.csv")
   total[i] = 1

pos = sum(total.values())
print(pos)
inventoryTable = pd.read_csv("Inventory_Table.csv", index_col = 0)
```

Comment: There are many similar question on Stackoverflow with good answers. One way is to use `df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable 'i' runs from index 0 to the number of 'newEntries'. When you add new data to row 'i' in your Pandas dataframe, you are overwriting existing data in that row. If you want to add new data, try 'n+i' where n is the initial number of entries. You can determine n with either

```
n = len(entryTable)
```

or

```
n = entryTable.shape[0]
```

Comment: I'm trying something like this:
for i in range(newEntries):
    if len(entryTable) == 0:
        n = 0
    else:
        n = len(entryTable)
    ID = input ("ID?\n")
    VQ = int (input ("VQ?\n"))
    timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    entryTable.loc[n + i] = [timeStamp, ID, VQ]
    entryTable.to_csv("Entry_Table.csv")
    total[i] = 1
All else being the same, I get this error: ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns in entryTable.loc[n + i] = [timeStamp, ID, VQ]